# Set variable by name in scope javascript

Tags: javascript, function, scope, namespaces

I'm trying to modify a object in a scope by it's name. Only solution I could think of is to stringify the new object and use eval to parse it and replace the original object. This works without any problems, but it doesn't look pretty and the JSON conversion creates unnecessary burden for the CPU. Is there any smarter way to this? Thank you!

```js
var app = new (function() {
  var test = {"value": "original"};
  this.showTestValue = function(){
    alert(test.value);
  };
  this.setVariable = function(key, value){
    eval(key+"=JSON.parse('"+JSON.stringify(value)+"')");
  }
})();
app.setVariable("test", {"value": "modified"});
app.showTestValue();
if(app.test !== undefined) alert("ERROR: Variable public");
if(typeof test !== "undefined") alert("ERROR: Global scope not clean");
```

Comment: hi, honestly I don't get why you don't pass the object as parameter(argument)... can you explain it?  thank you

Comment: `function set(objName, key, value){ eval(objName)[key]=value}`

Comment: Isn't this: this.setVariable = function(key, value){ eval(app)[key]=value; } same as this this.setVariable = function(key, value){ this[key]=value; }? I don't want to make the variable publicly accessible in my application, so it is not an option.